Cartoon, anime, or donghua that is centered around two brothers fighting for something
It mainly centers around two brothers fighting (probably for the throne or something like that). The evil brother has purple hair and wields a spear while the good brother has black hair and wields a sword (I think).
They still ride horses in this anime. I think the first scene might be when the good brother is watching a chicken fight between a black and brown chicken and, while the other people bet for the black chicken since it is apparently the more likely winner, he bets on the brown one with confidence and the brown one is the one that actually wins.
I'm not sure if the good brother is the main character, or if it's this other guy who is my favorite character. He is the good brother's advisor and plays the flute. He wears a long white kimono. He has this girl who likes him who is kind of a fighter, I think.
At the very end of the animation, the purple-haired evil brother dies an honorable death (I think) and the good brother celebrates his victory. But, the night before giving the rewards and stuff, the advisor guy leaves without taking a reward. He then goes to a mountain, which he is calling his master, and I think starts playing his flute. Eventually the other girl who likes him meets him there. I think the last scene is of them kissing on that mountain side, with the camera zooming farther and farther away from them.
The most important detail here is that it used to go on ST KUNGFU, like before Dragon Ball I think.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. - For example, when did you watch this?

https://scontent-lhr8-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/73482815_2145677952408803_5414055655294107648_n.png?stp=dst-png_s600x600&_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=13d280&_nc_ohc=adm9KBpgu40Q7kNvgEeXcrX&_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.xx&oh=00_AYAaNTD_2KLCAdl_bcuws3HbZIxeWqX-54VghGt_CUP_Qw&oe=66D3F75F

In 2017 something called "The King's War" used to be on before Dragonball

Thanks so much.I've been searching for that,for years.

I'm pretty sure that isn't the correct answer. King's War is a live-action TV show about chinese history; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59SK7gMNI9Q&ab_channel=HauVuAsianMovies

I found what I was looking for on the "on before Dragonball" link.It's the TV guide of that time.

Sure, but which show was the correct answer?

The Legend of Qin and Han Heroes

It led me to the real one which is"QINHAN YINGXIONG ZHUAN"

The problem though,is that I can't find where to watch it

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uSS-K-TWd2M
